# need to know steps to do hot deployment in Tomcat 6.X

Tags: deployment, tomcat6

I want to deploy the files (class files) without stopping the tomcat services. problem for me is as follows
I have one project with different domain names. which are running in one tomcat server. but if I deploy a class i need to stop tomcat each time this will effect for other domains.
So please suggest a solution to this problem.

---

Hi Romani,

Thanks for your reply

I'm using Tomcat manager to Stop the multiple application

I need,

1) Example **"myapp"** is application in tomcat

```
 C:\tomcat6.0\webapps\myapp\
```

2) I'm now *deploying class files* in **"myapp**" but *not stopping* **"myapp"** tomcat service

```
 C:\tomcat6.0\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes\**test.clas**s
```

3) Now **"test.class"** file has replaced in **myapp**

4) I'm opening http://localhost:8080/myapp

5) I need the changes of test.class file with no downtime of myapp application

```
     Is there any possibilities that deploying class files "without stop" "myapp" "Tomcat service"  in the Tomcat manager to reflect class file

     No down time with the application
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found the solution but I had the same issue and maybe this will help others. **This is only recommended for development environments.**
If you edit your context.xml file (for me that is located in [tomcat-root]/conf and add an attribute to the Context element: reloadable="true" like this:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

Then restart the server. You now have hot deployment on classes and libs as described here (without the need for manually restarting the application)

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes

Hope this helps you or someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try out following solution. this way you will stop and start only your application.

Do u have access to 'Tomcat web application manager'?

1) Go to `http://localhost:8080`

2) click on `Tomcat manager`

3) Then `stop` your deployed application

4) Then `replace` the class file/s in tomcat deployment directory

```
for e.g. C:\tomcat6.0\webapps\yourapp\WEB-INF\classes\....
```

5) Then again come back to `tomcat manager` and `start` your application.